Personalize your profile pop-up won't go away
This annoying pop-up won't go away, even after I personalize my profile. It can be removed with the "x" but shows up again whenever I refresh or open a new page. Is there any way I can get rid of it? I found one or two other people reporting this issue, but the only fix suggested was somehow programming an adblocker to remove it, which I don't know how to do. Thanks for any help.

Edit: This weirdly only seems to happen on Meta Stack Exchange and Worldbuilding Stack Exchange. Not on Worldbuilding Meta though. Very strange. Every other Stack Exchange I've visited doesn't have this bug for my profile.
Edit 2: Seems to be gone now somehow. Maybe because I showed I was an active user by posting a question? Still, hope the issue is solved soon.

@DanielT actually that most likely isn't monitored, so the better way to report bugs is by a new question.
