Weird box asking me to personalize my account is showing up incorrectly
I recently got this box as a pop up on a site where I have an account (Specifically saw it pop up on this page). It asks me to (reference picture):

Personalize your profile
Complete your profile by adding a display name and profile picture.

I have no idea when this popup became a thing that shows up, but I already have a profile picture and a display name. I did create the profile from my main account, so maybe it is incorrectly thinking it's a new account? Regardless, there is some sort of bug, as I shouldn't be seeing it at all, as I already have a username and profile picture on that site.

Related update: Upcoming changes to sign-up flow on the Stack Exchange network (section: Profile setup prompt)

@MetaAndrewT. ah, I see. doesnt appear that it was ever featured? so thats probably why i never saw the post. seems to be a bug if it is being shown to me.

Yes, it is a bug where users that joined a new community recently (with an existing account) are incorrectly shown this prompt.
We have resolved this issue for new sign-ups. For most users impacted by this bug, the prompt has already been dismissed and will not reappear once dismissed or clicked on. If you continue to see the prompt, please dismiss it. I hope this helps!

@marrados How about this question : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400804/personalize-your-profile-pop-up-wont-go-away?noredirect=1&lq=1
